# What type is passed as src charsequence/string or other in InputFilter?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-input-method, input-filter

I'm developing android application. My sdk details are **minimum sdk version is 7 and target and buid sdk version is 10**

In my app in one screen I'm using "EditText" and I'm using filter for that editText

The following are my coding snippet

```
editText.setFilters
        (
                new InputFilter[] 
                {
                        new InputFilter() 
                        {
                            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) 
                            {

                                String name=src.getClass().getName();
                                System.out.println("\n\tSrc class name ="+name);

                                String tempStr=((String)src).toUpperCase();



                                return tempStr;
                            }                           
                        }
                }
        );
```

In the above code sometimes src be the **String**,sometimes it be **CharSequence**,sometimes it be " **android.text.SpannableStringBuilder**"

My doubt is at what scenarios **charsequence is passed ,String is passed ,android.text.SpannableStringBuilder is passed as src**?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on CharSequence you used when calling TextView.setText(CharSequence text)

Comment: Kathir:im not using "editText.setText()" method to set the text.Im just accepting input from user (the user enters the text in the editText)